# pyqt5 QTimer.singleShot doesn't run at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

(Python 3.7.3, PyQt5m MacOS Mojave)

In the code that follows I was hoping to see

```
start_batch
item
item
item
item
returned from start_batch
```

but what I actually get is

```
start_batch
returned from start_batch
```

That is, simulated_item is never running,  not even once.

What do I need to do to correct this?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QCoreApplication, QThread
import time, sys

class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = -1

    def start_batch(self, operator_id, update_callback):
        print('start_batch')
        self.update_callback = update_callback
        QTimer.singleShot(1, self.simulated_item)

    def simulated_item(self):
        print('item')
        self.update_callback()
        self.num += 1
        if self.num > 4:
            self.normal_stop_callback()
            return
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.simulated_item)

class dummy(QThread):
    def update(self):
        print('update')

    def run(self):
        scnr = Scanner()
        scnr.start_batch('opid', self.update)
        print('returned from start_batch')
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep((0.2))

app = QCoreApplication([])
thread = dummy()
thread.run()
```

Comment: The big question is why do you expect what you indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have the error that you are calling the run method directly but that is not appropriate but you have to use the `start()` method:

```py
app = QCoreApplication([])
thread = dummy()
thread.start()
app.exec_()
```

But you still won't get what you want.

Many elements such as the case of QTimer (also the signals) need an event loop to be able to work but when you override the run method that has it by default you have eliminated it so it fails.

So an approximation of what you want may be the following code where the QTimer uses the QCoreApplication event loop:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QCoreApplication, QThread
import time, sys


class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = -1

    def start_batch(self, operator_id, update_callback):
        print("start_batch")
        self.update_callback = update_callback
        QTimer.singleShot(1, self.simulated_item)

    def simulated_item(self):
        print("item")
        # QTimer.singleShot() is used so that the update_callback function 
        # is executed in the thread where the QObject to which it belongs lives, 
        # if it is not a QObject it will be executed in the thread 
        # where it is invoked
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.update_callback)
        # self.update_callback()
        self.num += 1
        if self.num > 4:
            # self.normal_stop_callback()
            return
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.simulated_item)


class dummy(QThread):
    def update(self):
        print("update")

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.2)
        print("returned from start_batch")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    thread = dummy()
    thread.start()
    scnr = Scanner()
    thread.started.connect(lambda: scnr.start_batch("opid", thread.update))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllansec thanks for the info on the different threads and not overriding the use of the run method. When I try the example, however, scnr.start_batch, scnr.item, and dummy.update never run. Thanks to the info you provided I was able to convert your example into something that worked. The only way to post the is the "answer your own question" but I have checked your answer as to credit you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: @WesR My code is workable, test it in the CMD/terminal and not in an IDE as it can cause problems that prevent my code from working properly.

Comment: @eyllansec, when I copy your code from above and run it in in the terminal with no IDE the only output I see is
503$ python3 x.py 
returned from start_batch

Comment: @eyllansec, this replaces the previous reply, which I took too long to edit.

When I copy your code from above and run it in in the terminal with no IDE the only output I see is
503$ python3 x.py 
returned from start_batch

After that the process does not exit but produces no more output to the terminal. It does not respond to ^C  so I stopped the process manually.

I don't understand why it gives different results for each of us, but maybe there is a version difference?

Comment: @eyllansec, I gather from what your saying that the QTimer instance is alread a separate thread. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment to @eyllansec above, I was able to create a working example which is shown below.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QCoreApplication
import sys

class Scanner(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.num = -1
        self.app = app

    def simulated_item(self):
        self.num += 1
        print("item", self.num)
        if self.num <= 4:
            QTimer.singleShot(500, self.simulated_item)
        else:
            self.app.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    scnr = Scanner(app)
    scnr.simulated_item()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In your example the thread is irrelevant since it only serves to start the timer, for example remove `thread = QThread()` `thread.start()` and change `thread.started.connect(scnr.simulated_item)` with `QTimer.singleShot(0, scnr.simulated_item)` and it will work