Visual replacement of area of subwidgets in pair of custom widgets with a single widget in PyQt5?
In the example code below, I have a CustomWidget consisting of a main label (red) on top, and sub label (yellow) on bottom - and I instantiate several of those in a scroll area:

When I click on the "Merge" button, I'd like consecutive pairs of sub-labels to be replaced with a single sublabel, having the text of the left sub-label, and covering the area of both sub-labels - something like this (edited in image processing software):

So I thought, I'll just calculate the width of the "merged" sub-label, apply it to the left sub-label, and hide the right sub-label, to achieve this effect - unfortunately, this doesn't work, as it messes up the other previously set layout relationships - so the actual result looks something like this:

How can I achieve the kind of pairwise visual merging of sub-labels that I want?
The code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None, maintext=""):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.maintext = maintext
    self.origwidth = 50
    self.lbl_main = QLabel(self.maintext)
    self.lbl_main.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.lbl_main.setMinimumWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_main.setFixedWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_main.setFixedHeight(100)
    self.lbl_main.setStyleSheet("background: #3FFF0000;")
    self.lbl_sub = QLabel("sub_{}".format(self.maintext))
    self.lbl_sub.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.lbl_sub.setMinimumWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_sub.setFixedHeight(20)
    self.lbl_sub.setStyleSheet("background: #3FFFFF00; border: 1px solid black;")
    self.vspacer = QLabel()
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.layout.setSpacing(0)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_main)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_sub)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.vspacer)
    self.layout.setAlignment(self.lbl_main, Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.layout.setAlignment(self.lbl_sub, Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.num_cws = 10
    # Define the geometry of the main window
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle("my first window")
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
    self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    #self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
    self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll_central = QWidget()
    self.scroll_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_central)
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_central)
    self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
    self.btn = QPushButton(text = 'Merge')
    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onBtnClick)
    self.customwidgets = []
    for ix in range(self.num_cws):
      cw = CustomWidget(None, "{0}{0}".format(chr(65+ix)))
      self.scroll_layout.addWidget(cw)
      self.customwidgets.append(cw)
    self.show()

  def onBtnClick(self):
    if self.btn.text() == "Merge":
      self.btn.setText("Unmerge")
      for ix in range(0, self.num_cws, 2):
        cw_left = self.customwidgets[ix]
        cw_right = self.customwidgets[ix+1]
        llblgeom = cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().translated( cw_left.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_central, QPoint(0,0)) )
        rlblgeom = cw_right.lbl_sub.geometry().translated( cw_right.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_central, QPoint(0,0)) )
        lbl_dual_width = rlblgeom.right() - llblgeom.left()
        cw_right.lbl_sub.hide()
        cw_left.lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(lbl_dual_width)
    else:
      self.btn.setText("Merge")
      for ix in range(0, self.num_cws, 2):
        cw_left = self.customwidgets[ix]
        cw_right = self.customwidgets[ix+1]
        cw_left.lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(cw_left.origwidth)
        cw_right.lbl_sub.show()

if __name__== '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  myGUI = MyMainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())


That won't work. In your initial scenario, the widget hierarchy is simple and clear: parent -> [customWidget1 -> [label1A + label1B], customWidget2 -> [label2A + label2B], etc.]. What you want to achieve disrupts that hierarchy, as it would become something like: parent -> container -> [label1A + label2A + label1B]. What you may try is to create a widget that acts as intermediate container (with its own layout) and that could contain one or more "paired" widgets; when merging, that container will eventually show only the main labels of its children, and add the "merged sub label" to itself.

Thanks @musicamante - yeah, it seems that your suggestion of an intermediate container is the only thing that might work, I'll give that a try

You're welcome. Just remember that the Qt object tree ([grand]parent/[grand]child relations) works like physical objects, and that's even more important when dealing with widgets (item models/views and similar concepts like graphics views have a slightly different concept). A widget is similar to a box (a container): you cannot put the same object in two boxes. If you put a "label" (a "sticker") on a box, it's part of ("contained into") that box; if you put that one label across two boxes, it's not part of that box alone anymore, but of the "parent box" that may eventually contain them.

Note to self: this kind of thing is probably better done with QGridLayout, as it also supports overlapping / stacked widgets; see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/78863093/

@sddbs It can, but it can only be done programmatically (not from Designer, which you seem to be using as starting point). Also, using spanning on a widget that uses already occupied grid cells may have issues in spacing on non-spanned widgets depending on their size restraints or policies. In your specific case, the hierarchical separation will still be more consistent, even if it results in a more complex underlying layout management, because it also consider the logical hierarchy of objects.

OK, I think I found a solution for this - and since this was kind of tricky to get going properly, I thought I'd post an answer.
I was thinking about the intermediate container approach suggested by @musicamante, but I did not want to lose the "individuality" of my CustomWidgets - and then somehow I stumbled upon these resources mentioning QStackedLayout, which "allows you to position elements directly in front of one another", "where only one widget is visible at a time"

https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-layouts/
How to control widgets position insid QStackedLayout

However, it turns out that if you use QStackedLayout.StackAll, "All widgets are visible. The current widget is merely raised." (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html) - and you can also use .setGeometry to reposition widgets inside a QStackedLayout (though not before the layout has finished setting up). And finally, with the solution code below, I get what I wanted when "Merge" button is clicked:

So, in the solution code below, I started from this kind of setup:

... where the QStackedLayout is the "first" in the scroll area, and it then hosts a widget (.scroll_container) which contains the initial, single view of the CustomWidgets.
When "Merge" is clicked, the geometries for the dual labels are calculated, and the dual labels are created and added directly to the QStackedLayout in the onBtnClick - however, note:

Since QStackedLayout will be calculated after onBtnClick is finished, any .setGeometry on the dual labels will be ignored/overwritten - so we have to save their geometries, and apply them in a "delayed" function (.repositionDuals()), called via QTimer.singleShot (1 millisecond delay seems to be enough)
Even with the proper geometry applied by .repositionDuals(), the new dual labels will still appear "behind" the original single labels - so to handle this, we must call .setCurrentIndex(idx) method of QStackedLayout -- noting that the widget that hosts the original single CustomWidgets has index 0.
Because of this stacking organization, we cannot use label background color with transparency anymore, because otherwise the single and dual labels will be "seen through", and create a visual mess
Creation of sub labels should be moved into a class method, to ease creating of dual labels
When doing "Unmerge", we have to iterate the dual labels array in reverse, to delete them correctly

Note that in the below code, if you try to resize the main window while you have dual labels shown, their positioning will be messed up, so to handle that, you'd probably need some sort of positioning recalculation in the window's resizeEvent, for example.
Here is the working code - I've left my messy comments and printouts in the code below for reference:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
  origwidth = 50
  def __init__(self, parent=None, maintext=""):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.maintext = maintext
    #self.origwidth = 50
    self.lbl_main = QLabel(self.maintext)
    self.lbl_main.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.lbl_main.setMinimumWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_main.setFixedWidth(self.origwidth)
    self.lbl_main.setFixedHeight(100)
    self.lbl_main.setStyleSheet("background: #3FFF0000;")
    #self.lbl_sub = QLabel("sub_{}".format(self.maintext))
    #self.lbl_sub.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    #self.lbl_sub.setMinimumWidth(self.origwidth)
    #self.lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(self.origwidth)
    #self.lbl_sub.setFixedHeight(20)
    #self.lbl_sub.setStyleSheet("background: #3FFFFF00; border: 1px solid black;")
    self.lbl_sub = self.create_lbl_sub(self.maintext)
    self.vspacer = QLabel()
    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.layout.setSpacing(0)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_main)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_sub)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.vspacer)
    self.layout.setAlignment(self.lbl_main, Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.layout.setAlignment(self.lbl_sub, Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

  @classmethod
  def create_lbl_sub(cls, maintext):
    lbl_sub_text = maintext if maintext.startswith("sub_") else "sub_{}".format(maintext)
    lbl_sub = QLabel(lbl_sub_text)
    lbl_sub.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    lbl_sub.setMinimumWidth(cls.origwidth)
    lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(cls.origwidth)
    lbl_sub.setFixedHeight(20)
    #lbl_sub.setStyleSheet("background: #3FFFFF00; border: 1px solid black;") # do not use alpha, the overlaid labels will be see-through and create mess with labels below
    lbl_sub.setStyleSheet("background: #F4F4B5; border: 1px solid black;")
    return lbl_sub

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.num_cws = 10
    #self.repos_timer = QTimer() # https://stackoverflow.com/q/23860665 ;  this repeats
    #self.repos_timer.timeout.connect(self.repositionDuals)
    # Define the geometry of the main window
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle("my first window")
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
    self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    #self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    #
    self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
    self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll_central = QWidget(self)
    self.scroll_slayout = QStackedLayout(self.scroll_central) #QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_central)
    self.scroll_slayout.setStackingMode(QStackedLayout.StackAll)
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_central)
    self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
    #
    self.scroll_container = QWidget(self)
    self.cont_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_container)
    self.scroll_slayout.addWidget(self.scroll_container)
    #
    self.btn = QPushButton(text = 'Merge')
    self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onBtnClick)
    self.customwidgets = []
    for ix in range(self.num_cws):
      cw = CustomWidget(None, "{0}{0}".format(chr(65+ix)))
      self.cont_layout.addWidget(cw)
      self.customwidgets.append(cw)
    self.dual_labels = []
    self.show()

  def onBtnClick(self):
    if self.btn.text() == "Merge":
      self.btn.setText("Unmerge")
      for ix in range(0, self.num_cws, 2):
        cw_left = self.customwidgets[ix]
        cw_right = self.customwidgets[ix+1]
        #print(f"{self.scroll_container.geometry()=}") # (0, 0, 572, 163)
        #print(f"{cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().topLeft()=} {cw_left.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_container, QPoint(0,0))=}") # (0, 100) .. (9, 115)
        #print(f"{cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry()=} {cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().translated( cw_left.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_container, QPoint(0,0)) - cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().topLeft() )=}") # (0, 100, 50, 20) .. (9, 115, 50, 20)
        llblgeom = cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().translated( cw_left.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_container, QPoint(0,0)) - cw_left.lbl_sub.geometry().topLeft() )
        rlblgeom = cw_right.lbl_sub.geometry().translated( cw_right.lbl_sub.mapTo(self.scroll_container, QPoint(0,0)) - cw_right.lbl_sub.geometry().topLeft() )
        lbl_dual_width = rlblgeom.right() - llblgeom.left()
        #cw_right.lbl_sub.hide()
        #cw_left.lbl_sub.setFixedWidth(lbl_dual_width)
        dual_rect = QRect(llblgeom.topLeft(), QSize(lbl_dual_width+1, llblgeom.height()))
        dual_lbl = CustomWidget.create_lbl_sub( cw_left.lbl_sub.text() )
        self.scroll_slayout.addWidget(dual_lbl)
        #print(cw_left.lbl_sub.text(), dual_rect)
        dual_lbl.dual_rect = dual_rect # add property dynamically
        dual_lbl.setFixedWidth(lbl_dual_width+1)
        dual_lbl.setGeometry(dual_rect) # does not work here
        self.dual_labels.append(dual_lbl)
      #self.repositionDuals() # does not work here, must use singleShot to delay
      QTimer.singleShot(1, self.repositionDuals) # as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/59637527 #self.repos_timer.start(1) #
    else:
      self.btn.setText("Merge")
      print(len(self.dual_labels), self.dual_labels)
      for i in range(len(self.dual_labels)-1, -1, -1): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406
        tdlbl = self.dual_labels[i]
        self.scroll_slayout.removeWidget(tdlbl) # https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899826
        tdlbl.deleteLater()
        del self.dual_labels[i] # self.dual_labels.remove(tdlbl) # both work, if iterating in reverse
      #print(len(self.dual_labels), self.dual_labels) # still 2 hanging in here with .remove, unless we iterate in reverse
  #
  def repositionDuals(self):
    print("repositionDuals")
    for ix, tdlbl in enumerate(self.dual_labels):
      print(tdlbl.dual_rect, tdlbl.geometry())
      #oldgeom = tdlbl.geometry() # test
      #tdlbl.setGeometry(oldgeom.left()+ix*10, oldgeom.top()+10, oldgeom.width(), oldgeom.height())
      tdlbl.setGeometry(tdlbl.dual_rect)
      # MUST call setCurrentIndex for each widget individually so it raises on top,
      # considering that the main/default elements are in self.scroll_container on index 0
      self.scroll_slayout.setCurrentIndex(1+ix)

if __name__== '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  myGUI = MyMainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

